# Gradle could not find org.ehcache:ehcache:. after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.x

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, ehcache-3

I'm currently in the progress of upgrading a Spring Boot Gradle project from 2.7.x to 3.0.x. In this project we've declarated the Ehcache library as a API dependency:

```
api 'org.ehcache:ehcache'
```

After reading [the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#ehcache3), I've changed this to the following:

```
api('org.ehcache:ehcache') {
    capabilities {
        requireCapability('org.ehcache:ehcache-jakarta')
    }
}
```

However after running `./gradlew build`, Gradle failed to resolve the dependency:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.ehcache:ehcache:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

I've tried the following possible workarounds:

```
api 'org.ehcache:ehcache-jakarta'
```

Does not work.

```
api 'org.ehcache:ehcache:jakarta'
```

Does not work.

However, when declaring a version it does work:

```
api 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.8:jakarta'
```

But why declare a version if this is managed by Spring Boot?

**Spring Boot version:** 3.0.4
**Gradle Wrapper version**: 7.6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure a dependency with a classifier and without a version like this:

```
api("org.ehcache:ehcache::jakarta")
```

Note the `::` that omits the version.

For Spring Boot's dependency management to apply correctly in this instance, you'll have to use Gradle's built-in platform support rather than the dependency management plugin:

```
api(platform(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))
```

Comment: It works in my sample project. However in our large multi-module project, which is still setup the old way (with buildscript), the `publishToMavenLocal` task fails.
`org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Duplicated tag: 'dependencyManagement' (position: START_TAG seen ...</dependencies>\n  <dependencyManagement>... @148:25)`

Comment: Are you using both the dependency management plugin and Gradle's platform support in the same project? If so, you are hitting https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/21277. I'd recommend only using one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another workaround.

```
implementation "org.ehcache:ehcache:${dependencyManagement.importedProperties['ehcache3.version']}:jakarta"
```

https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing-properties